# Installing Geant4 alongside GEANT-3, and Root 6 alongside Root 5

Tags: path, multipath-storage

Can I install [Geant4](http://geant4.web.cern.ch/geant4/) alongside GEANT-3 on my Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)? I have already installed [GEANT-3](https://dberzano.github.io/alice/install-aliroot/manual/#geant_3_(optional)) by the [AliRoot installation method](https://dberzano.github.io/alice/install-aliroot/auto/) shown by [Dario Berzano](https://dberzano.github.io/). How can I install [Geant4](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/geant4-vmc) without making any problems?

Same goes with [Root](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/downloading-root) by CERN. The latest pro version is [6.04](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/production-version-604), while the widely used pro version is [5.34](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/production-version-534). While I am working on Root 5, can I install and run version 6 alongside version 5?

If I can, how do I do it and why is this possible or if it is not then why so ?

Comment: I took every precaution I could ( http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3585/84855 ) before asking it here. Still the downveotes?! It hurts. What went wrong?

Comment: There's nothing glaringly wrong with this, and mystery downvotes on a question are impossible to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a user of these things so I cannot answer your question precisely, but since you haven't gotten anything else, I can make a few suggestions.

The instructions you linked from the [Automatic AliRoot installation page](https://dberzano.github.io/alice/install-aliroot/auto/) unfortunately depend on a black box installer with very few apparent options.  I am guessing Mr. Berzano thought this was a nice thing to do, but as we can see in this case, it perhaps is not so great.

With a normal build/install, you have the option of picking a prefix directory.  If you can find a way to do that for this, your problem is solved -- just create, e.g., `/opt/geant4` and install into there.  That most likely will (aka, *should*) result in a `/opt/geant4/bin` and probably a `/opt/geant4/lib`, among whatever else.

When you then want to use Geant4 instead of 3, use a short shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

installDir=/opt/geant4
export PATH=${installDir}/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${installPath}/lib/
```

You could then add whatever command you use to start the application and run it that way *or* you could source it into your current context, `source whatever.sh` (short form: `. whatever.sh`).  **If you just run it, the variables will not apply to that context.**

This sets the shell's search path for executables giving the stuff in `/opt/geant4` precedence, so if the application is just called `geant` and you have version 3 already installed normally, executing `geant` will now invoke `/opt/geant4/bin/geant` instead if it exists.  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does something similar for the linker, which associates executables with whatever libraries they need (I am presuming geant includes some of those).

Note that sourcing and exporting variables will apply only to your current shell and its children (i.e., it is not universal) so you could run both versions at once.

You may want to write to Mr. Berzano and ask him about this issue.  There could be a simple way to circumvent the black box installer, if it is simply a wrapper around a more normative "manual" method to which the above logic could be applied.  I notice there is an email address if you click through to the "about.me" page linked at the bottom.  If you refer to this Q&A, he will understand what I am talking about.

Comment: I will see how it goes and let you know.